# Why does the DjangoJSONEncoder not deal with proxy objects?

Tags: python, json, django

So this is the code from DjangoJSONEncoder, it handles most things that are needed beyond the standard json encoder:

```
class DjangoJSONEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    """
    JSONEncoder subclass that knows how to encode date/time and decimal types.
    """
    def default(self, o):
        # See "Date Time String Format" in the ECMA-262 specification.
        if isinstance(o, datetime.datetime):
            r = o.isoformat()
            if o.microsecond:
                r = r[:23] + r[26:]
            if r.endswith('+00:00'):
                r = r[:-6] + 'Z'
            return r
        elif isinstance(o, datetime.date):
            return o.isoformat()
        elif isinstance(o, datetime.time):
            if is_aware(o):
                raise ValueError("JSON can't represent timezone-aware times.")
            r = o.isoformat()
            if o.microsecond:
                r = r[:12]
            return r
        elif isinstance(o, decimal.Decimal):
            return str(o)
        else:
            return super(DjangoJSONEncoder, self).default(o)
```

But when it tries to encode a proxy object it fails with `django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0x7f53c6325ed0> is not JSON serializable`

This is pretty easy to fix by changing DjangoJSONEncoder to:

```
from django.utils.functional import Promise
class DjangoJSONEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    """
    JSONEncoder subclass that knows how to encode date/time and decimal types.
    """
    def default(self, o):
        # See "Date Time String Format" in the ECMA-262 specification.
        if isinstance(o, datetime.datetime):
            r = o.isoformat()
            if o.microsecond:
                r = r[:23] + r[26:]
            if r.endswith('+00:00'):
                r = r[:-6] + 'Z'
            return r
        elif isinstance(o, datetime.date):
            return o.isoformat()
        elif isinstance(o, datetime.time):
            if is_aware(o):
                raise ValueError("JSON can't represent timezone-aware times.")
            r = o.isoformat()
            if o.microsecond:
                r = r[:12]
            return r
        elif isinstance(o, decimal.Decimal):
            return str(o)
        elif isinstance(o, Promise):  # Added these lines here 
            return unicode(o)
        else:
            return super(DjangoJSONEncoder, self).default(o)
```

but the guys that write Django are pretty smart.  If this was the real fix, they would probably have already done it.  Why have they NOT done it, what about that call to unicode, combined with JSON encoding makes this the wrong fix for the DjangoJSONEncoder?

I even find a [reference to this problem](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/serialization/#serialization-formats-json) in the Django docs, so it isn't like it's not known, I just don't understand why it isn't the default.

Comment: Why not resolve the promise before trying to encode it? There is no obvious way to resolve a `Proxy` instance as the implementation of `Proxy` is just a `pass`.

Comment: Because I'm not trying to encode it, other things are, and the proxy object is buried inside another object and potentially another object.....